# Ubuntu is not starting up after a RAM upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, memory, ubuntu-22.04

Recently I upgraded my notebook from 6 GB of RAM (4 GB + 2 GB) to 16 GB (8 GB + 8 GB). The notebook has Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 22.04 installed on dualboot. When I initialize the Windows it works fine, and I can even see that the 16 GB are working:

[image: CPU-Z Memory tab showing the RAM memory]

However when I try to initialize the computer on Ubuntu it does not work: after the loading screen a bunch of text appear for an instant (I was not able to read it) and the screen goes black forever.

Is this a problem with the RAM sticks, Ubuntu, or even something else?

UPDATE:

I tried to boot Ubuntu on recovery mode to see if I could fix something, and I found out that Ubuntu is probably also recognizing the new memory:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the RAM is only marginally compatible with your motherboard, and Ubuntu lacks the driver for it.

Comment: Are you sure ubuntu boots up normally with the old RAM modules installed?

Answer (score 1):

1. Older versions of Ubuntu relied on a [swap partition](https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/03-adding-swap-partition-on-ubuntu-16.html), but 22.04 LTS uses a [swap file](https://devanswers.co/creating-swap-space-ubuntu-18-04/). If you've enabled hibernation, swap space is required *at least* the size of RAM. If the swap space is in use, that could cause the issue of not booting. In that case, revert to 6 GB, reboot Ubuntu and resize the swap space to at least 16 GB (I'd allow a few extra GB). Try a **full** shutdown, inserting the two 8 GB cards, and rebooting.
2. If that does not work, one way to try to fix the issue without diagnosing the cause is to reinstall Ubuntu. **First make a disk image, using Linux dd or a Windows application such as [free Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree)** (it does not matter if done from Windows or Linux, since the image is of the *entire disk*). Then, using a live Ubuntu USB, [reinstall Ubuntu, attempting to keep data](https://www.fosslinux.com/2920/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-by-keep-your-data-safe-in-event-of-system-failure.htm), if that option is available. However, you might need to install, overwriting the Ubuntu partition, losing data, anyway.

   Test that you can boot both Windows and Ubuntu. Then, if need be, restore *just the Ubuntu partition* from the disk image. Hopefully, the boot configuration created by the reinstallation will allow you to continue to dual boot.